# IDE for Django web development

Tags: django, ide

I'm getting ready to start developing web content (simple web pages, heavy duty web services) in Django.  What are my options for IDEs?  What are the good points and bad points?  Is Aptana in Eclipse good for this.  I would like to be able to easily push my updates to the remote server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Django Pydev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html) - Eclipse plugin for developing Django/Python Apps. It's free.

[Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) - Python and Django IDE from JetBrains(people who brought us IntelliJ IDE). Not free.

Update: There is community edition of Pycharm, which is free, although it does not have all the features of the Professional edition. Check out the [feature comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: Since I really like the possibility of using Eclipse, the first option sounds interesting.  How does it deal with remote SVN repositories?

Comment: Eclipse does have plugins for SVN support. Being a Git user in the command line, I don't really know how good it is. But accessing remote repos seems to be a trivial feature that should be supported in the plugin.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried all IDEs. I have Been using Eclipse+PyDev for the past few months. I recently switched to [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). I think it's got the whole package. Not free, though. However I think its price is right. Although I can get it for free through the university which I study as a PhD student, I seriously consider paying for it.

Yes, PyCharm is free for opensource projects and educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse+PyDev, NetBeans, Eric in the past. Pycharm is a best choice ever, especially for web development with Django.

Answer (score 1):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) works well for Django & Python2/3 *(and any language, really)*. It comes with all of the basics installed, and for things that aren't installed it gives you a normal Ubuntu VM, which you have full root access to. So you aren't limited to what is already on Koding :)

Answer (score 0):

Im using Pycharm, PyCharm by Jetbrain is amazing. there are two versions, community version and Pro version. Pro versions supports for Django. not the community version. Pro version is not free. But still you can use pro version for educational porposes. if you can educational institute email. you can register jetbrains website and confirm the email. and download pro version and register using the your institute email.

Version controlling: Its easy with PyCham also.
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/publishing-a-project-on-github.html
[image]

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple IDEs, including Eclipse with PyDev, and Aptana Studio. PyCharm from JetBrains is by far the most convenient and lightweight IDE for Python and Django development.

If you are working on open source projects, it is the best you can go for, since they offer free license to Open Source projects/Educational purposes. They do verify this before they provide you with a license.

There is also the option of SSH, Terminal, Version Control, Python Console, Django Admin command console within the IDE which I think are great features to have.